# '$f''(x)\mid f(x)\iff f(x)=c(x-a)^n$, if $f(x)$ has no monofactor'

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> How to prove: $f''(x)\mid f(x)$ if and only if $f(x)=c(x-a)^n$, if $f(x)$ has no monofactor.
> Here, $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n\geq 2$ in a field $\Bbb P$, and it has no monofator means all irreducible factor has power $\geq 2$ in the factorization of $f$.

I know the classical result: $f'(x)\mid f(x)\leftrightarrows f(x)=c(x-a)^n$. What is the idea for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean $\Leftrightarrow$? \Leftrightarrow And why does $c(x-a)^n$ have no monofactor?

Comment: $\Leftrightarrow$ is just if and only if.  it has no monofator means all irreducible factor has power $\geq 2$ in the factorization of $f$.

Comment: In this case you should edit your question and explicitly explain the meaning of $ \leftrightarrows$.